# Tail Recursion in Scala with Base case as zero

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

Suppose I have this code in scala :

```
def factorial(accumulator: Int, x: Int) : Int = {
  if(x == 1)
    return accumulator
  factorial(x * accumulator, x - 1)
}
println(factorial(1,0))
```

And the Output :

```
0
```

Now I have two questions :

1) Isn't the definition of this function fundamentally wrong? ( will not give the right answer for zero) I could always wrap this function inside another function and treat zero as special case returning 1 but that does not feel right and in tune with the formal definition.

2) Also why I am returned 0 as the answer in the first place? Why doesn't the code get stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: Just a guess, but does it take a _really_ long time to return `0` with you pass in `0`? As in, longer than if you pass in, say, `4`.

Comment: Yes, it does take longer.

Comment: Okay, now. What happens to an `Int` when it exceeds it's maximum negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def factorial(x: Int): Int = {

    @annotation.tailrec
    def factorial(accumulator: Int, x: Int): Int = {

      if (x <= 0)
        accumulator
      else
        factorial(x * accumulator, x - 1)

    }

    assert(x >= 0,"""argument should be "non-negative integer" """)
    factorial(1, x)

}
```

- You should not give user possibility to call factorial in wrong way. So your function should be internal
- [factorial(0) = 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

Comment: Just a nitpick, but I'd use `require` rather than `assert` - the former is meant to validate input parameters, the later to ensure that output values make sense, I think.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo [for output values there is `ensuring`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L43), though looks like in scala community nobody really uses it. Require is a pre-condition, ensuring is a post condition and assert is a check which is used by external method to validate correct result.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you should hide the accumulator and make it an argument of an internal, tailrec function. The special case for zero should also be handled explicitly, there is nothing 'against formal factorial definition' with it.
2. It works because integer exceeds the maximum negative value.